# Create a supervised classifier based on decision trees

Tags: r

I need help in R program language which i have to answer this question : ) (a) Create a supervised classifier based on decision trees. (b) Randomly split into training and test set to determine the prediction quality of your classifier.

I did this code but i just get same result for all categories. is there anybody to help me???

```
libery(tree)
quality<- as.numeric(winequality.red$quality) 
range(quality) #8.4  14.9   

High = ifelse(winequality.red$quality >= 5, "Yes","No")
winequality.red2 = data.frame(winequality.red, High)
winequality.red2 = winequality.red2[,-12]


#divide data into testing and training
set.seed(2)
train = sample(1:nrow(winequality.red2), nrow(winequality.red2)/2) # half for testing and halof for training
test = -train
training_data = winequality.red2[train, ]
testing_data = winequality.red2[test, ]
testing_Test = High[test]

tree_model = tree(test~., training_data)
plot(tree_model)
text(tree_model, pretty= 0 )

tree_Pred = predict(tree_model, testing_data)
mean(tree_Pred !=testing_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Rpart better than tree. it does cross validation internally if that is what you meant. be sure to use rpart.plot::prp to plot them nicely. There is enough documentation on the packages from here.

Answer (score 0):

but this i am doing must be in tree which i always get same result when i change numbers or variables. then i have to compare the result by random forests .  the quetion whic i have to cover by these codes are 
1) (a) Create a supervised classifier based on decision trees. (b) Randomly split into training and test set to determine the prediction quality of your classifier

I wanna make sure i did right or not....